# Show that $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I tried to prove that $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ is a tautology.

I used $p$ and $¬q$ as conditions. (Premises 1 and 5)

I managed to get to a solution, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Can you please check it?

Thank you!!!:)[image]

Comment: Is each step valid according to whatever the rules of your proof system (which you're not showing)? If so, it is right.

Comment: I don't know what rules you're using. But I'd find it strange if some of the stuff you're using is a valid rule. For instance getting $\neg\neg p\lor q$ from $p\lor q$. Maybe it's, right, I don't know. But to get $\neg \neg p\lor q$, I'd first expect you to derive $\neg\neg p$ from $p$ and then introduce $\neg \neg p\lor q$.

Comment: You misused modus tollens. Assuming $\lnot q$, given $\lnot p \rightarrow q$, gives you $\lnot \lnot p \equiv p$, by modus tollens. You infer $\lnot p$.

Comment: The step from (12) to (13) looks fishy. Note that 12 has to be $p\to(\neg q\to (q\to p))$ in order to be concluded by the deduction theorem; you appear to be trying to rewrite it as if it were $(p\to \neg q)\to(q\to p)$, which (a) is not the same, and (b) would produce $(\neg p \lor \neg q)\to\cdots$ rather than $\neg(p\lor \neg q)\to\cdots$. Even if the rewriting worked, do you have rules that allow you to do that sort of things to _subformulas_ anyway?

Comment: Also at $8)$, you have $\lnot p \land \lnot q$. Using DeMorgans, you get $\lnot(p \lor q)$, which is not equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is pretty simple to derive using truth tables:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Regarding step 11 :

> $\lnot q \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$

it is a *tautology*; so, it is provable.

You are trying to prove it from assumptions; you can simplify it as follows :

1) $p$ --- assumed

2) $\lnot q$ --- assumed

3) $\lnot q \lor p$ --- Add.2

4) $q \rightarrow p$ --- Impl.3

5) $\lnot q \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ --- C.P.2-4

Then discharge assumption $p$ to get :

> 6) $p \rightarrow (\lnot q \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p))$ --- C.P.1-5

but from it, you cannot derive 13) : $\lnot (p \lor \lnot q) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ ...

You must have :

13') $(p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ --- by [Exportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_%28logic%29)

Then we have :

14') $\lnot (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$ --- from 13') by the equivalence : $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow \lnot (p \land \lnot q)$ ... but we have to justify it !

and finally :

> > $(p \rightarrow q) \lor (q \rightarrow p)$ --- Impl.14'.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quicker way than your approach.

By the law of excluded middle, $p \lor \neg p$

If $p$, then ...

If $\neg p$, then ...

Remember, anything implies a true statement, and a false statement implies anything.

edit: I'm just suggesting that you start with $p \lor \neg p$, which is either an axiom or derivable from $p \dashv \vdash \neg \neg p$, depending on which book you use.

Comment: The LEM might not even be an axiom. I'd expected it not to be.

Comment: thanks! i'm not sure i understood the way you suggested...

Comment: @GitGud - please, note that the OP's formula (called Dummett's law) is **not** *intuitionistically valid*; thus, in order to prove it, we have to use somewhere a "classical" principle, like *LEM* or *Double Negation* or the equivalence between $\lnot p \rightarrow q$ and $p \lor q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My point was that assuming the LEM is assuming too much. In this context, it needs to be proved.

Comment: @GitGud It's one of the most fundamental tenets of mathematical thinking. If it (or an equivalent statement) is not invokable at the start of the argument, then you're working with your hands tied.

Comment: @GFauxPas Then you might as well just start the proof with the conclusion. There's no reason to draw the line at LEM. And you claim it is a 'tenet', I've never in my life seen the LEM as an axiom, never. **Edit:** Except for when all tautologies are taken as axioms, but this would run into what I said at the start of this comment.

Comment: @GitGud Google "(Aristotle's) three laws of thought" for more information on the importance of LEM.

Comment: @GFauxPas Not outdated at all.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't think they are, to be honest. I think most people are oblivious to elementary logic facts and this shows in the way people asks questions. Sometimes they actually know what the text question is asking, but they fail to ask the question here properly. Then there's those who equate provability to truth as if completeness was a trivial matter... **Edit:** By the way, the word is [*partially*](https://translate.google.com/#auto/it/partially).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Given the logical fact that a disjunction is true as long as long as at least one statement is true:
[image]

- Work from all the variables first
- Implications
- Disjunction from implications

The final result is that it is true in all possible worlds, a tautology.