# How can it be that $(P \rightarrow Q) \vee (Q \rightarrow P)$ is a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I consider $(P \rightarrow Q) \vee (Q \rightarrow P)$, that is $(\neg P \vee Q) \vee (\neg Q \vee P)$ and so $\neg P \vee Q \vee \neg Q \vee P$, which is a tautology.

It seems strange to me that, given two arbitrary formulas, necessarily  one implies the other or viceversa. (I am thinking for example of this case: P stands for 'Ann loves animals' and Q 'Ann is a student')

Where is my mistake? Perhaps in the interpretation of $P$ and $Q$?

Any clarification will be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no mistake : it is a tautology. You can see also this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121987/show-that-p-to-q-lor-q-to-p-is-a-tautology).

Comment: The left part is false only if $[P\wedge\neg{Q}]$, but that makes the right part true.

Comment: I think your issue is actually in your interpretation of $\rightarrow$; as the decomposition $P\rightarrow Q = \neg P \vee Q$ indicates, $\rightarrow$ is *not* a causal implication, only a material implication.  $P$ and $Q$ need not have really anything in common for $P\rightarrow Q$ to be true.

Comment: Your mistake is in the interpretation of "implies". The logical symbol $\to$ has _nothing_ to do with causation.

Comment: Your question could be generalized to "why is $(P \rightarrow A) \lor (B \rightarrow P)$ always true?"  $A=B$ is just a special case.

Comment: I think almost everyone agrees that there are ways in which $\to$ is not a good model of implication, and that this demonstrates one of them. Wikipedia has an article on [paradoxes of material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradoxes_of_material_implication) that cites this example specifically. In intuitionistic logic, $\to$ has a different interpretation, and $(A\to B)\lor(B\to A)$ is *not* a tautology; some people prefer intuitionistic logic for this reason.

Comment: @MJD Thank you very much for the article:)

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because it is *not* about the proof of the proposition, but rather about implication and how "unintuitive" it may seem to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proposition $(P \rightarrow Q) \vee (Q \rightarrow P)$ is always true.  This does *not* mean that either $P \rightarrow Q$ is always true or $Q \rightarrow P$ is always true.  Isn't that what you said?

Comment: Thank you...Oh ok, that was my problem!

Answer (score 8):

The kicker is to remember that a true statement is implied by any statement, and that a false statement implies every statement. (This is one upshot of the fact that $A\to B\equiv\neg A\vee B.$ The other is that a true statement does not imply a false statement.) Hence, if P is true or P is false, then your compound statement is true.

To clarify that last sentence, let's consider your particular example statements, in light of the possibilities. Does Ann love animals? If so, then $Q\to P$ holds; if not, then $P\to Q$ holds. Regardless, one of the two implications is true, and so $(P\to Q)\vee(Q\to P)$ is necessarily true.

Answer (score 3):

Remember the definition of implication.

$P \rightarrow Q$ means $\lnot P \lor Q$ In words, either $P$ is false or $Q$ is true.

$Q\rightarrow P$ means $\lnot Q \lor P$ In words, either $Q$ is false or $P$ is true.

Putting it all together gives us $$(P\rightarrow Q) \lor (Q\rightarrow P) \equiv \lnot P \lor Q \lor \lnot Q \lor P \equiv P\lor \lnot P \lor Q \lor \lnot Q$$

The above cannot logically be false. Either $P$ is true or $\lnot P $ is true, not to mention we also have $Q \lor \lnot Q$.  You can verify the tautology by using a truth table.

Recall that material implication tells us nothing about the *relevance* of $P$ with respect to $Q$, nor that of $Q$ with respect to $P$.  That is, material implication does not necessarily signify any causal relation between one proposition and another.

This is what may seem very counter-intuitive because in natural language, we think of one event implying another event as being causal, or otherwise being based on some relevant relationship between one statement and another. In logic, we are not to take $P\rightarrow Q$ as saying anything more than "either $P$ is false, or $Q$ is true."

Comment: @Arthur: I am *interpreting* explicitly what implication says, and what it does not claim, which may seem counter-intuitive

Comment: I removed my comment after you added your content (it made my previous comment irrelevant), but here is why I said what I said: I feel it's very important in mathematics in general to gain intuition beyond merely what rules tell us. Your original answer was basically just a repeat of the OP's argument as a confirmation that there were indeed no mistakes. However, the OP didn't ask for that. They asked for an intuitive justification for why it is the way it is, in order to further understand the _moral_ of the story. Your original answer provided nothing of that.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes logical implication is not that intuitive.

For your $P$ and $Q$ we have the following:

Either Ann loves animals, or she doesn't. If she does, then $Q\to P$ is true.

If she doesn't, then $P\to Q$ is true.

Either way one of the components in the disjunction is true.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, it means that either the statement

> If Ann loves animals, then Ann is a student

Or the statement

> If Ann is a student, then Ann loves animals.

(or both) is correct.

If Ann is, indeed, a student, then the first statement is true if she loves animals or not. If Ann is *not* a student, then any statement beginning with "If Ann is a student" is correct, so , in conclusion:

- If Ann is a student, statement 1 is correct. Statement 2 may or may not be correct (it is correct if Ann indeed loves animals and incorrect if she does not), but that is irrelevant.
- If Ann is not a student, then statement 2 is correct. Statement 1 may or may not be correct (it is correct iff Ann does not love animals), but again, that is irrelevant.