# Proving a sequent is valid without a premise

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction

I'm having issues proving that a sequent is valid, without any premises given.

1. Prove $⊢ (p \to q) \lor (q \to r)$ by natural deduction.
2. Prove $⊢ \forall x \forall y P(x, y) \to \exists y \forall x P(x, y)$ by natural deduction.

I don't know where to begin with, as I normally use my premises in the first place. What's the general approach when encountering a sequent like theses ones?

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121987/show-that-p-to-q-lor-q-to-p-is-a-tautology/1123296#1123296 there is a (correct and interesting) answer for the first question in a "sort of" natural deduction style, but I can't consider it as a real natural deduction proof because it relies on some well-known classical equivalences for which the answer does not provide a natural deduction derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preliminary**: in the derivations below, $[A]^i$ means that the formula $A$ has been discharged, the index $i$ shows where.

**Concerning the first question**, the formula $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ is valid only in classical logic, not in intuitionistic logic. This means that, as suggested by Bram28, the proof of $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ in natural deduction must use some inference rule (e.g. *reductio ad absurdum*) or equivalently some axiom (e.g. *tertium non datur*) valid only in classical logic. The following is a derivation in natural deduction of $(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)$ assuming the classical axiom *tertium non datur* $p \lor \lnot p$:
$$
\dfrac{p \lor \lnot p \qquad \dfrac{\dfrac{[p]^1}{q \to p}\small{\to_{intro}}}{(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)}{\small\lor_{intro}} \qquad \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\lnot p]^1 \qquad [p]^2}{\bot}\small{\lnot_{elim}}}{q}\small{\textit{efq}}}{p \to q}\small{\to_{intro} 2}}{(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)}\small{\lor_{intro}}}{(p \to q) \lor (q \to p)}\small{\lor_{elim} \ 1}
$$

If you aren't allowed to use the law of *tertium non datur* as an axiom, then you can derive it using the rule of *reductio ad absurdum* as below, the derivation you are looking for being the composition of the two (plug the second derivation above $p \lor \lnot p$ in the first derivation).
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{[\lnot(p \lor \lnot p)]^1 \qquad \dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\lnot(p \lor \lnot p)]^1 \qquad \dfrac{[p]^2}{p \lor \lnot p}\small{\lor_{intro}}}{\bot}\small{\lnot_{elim}}}{\lnot p}\small{\lnot_{intro} \ 2}}{p \lor \lnot p}\small{\lor_{intro}}}{\bot}\small{\lnot_{elim}}}{p \lor \lnot p}\small{{raa} \ 1}
$$

**Concerning the second question**, the idea is that you suppose that everyone is in relation with everyone, then in particular (since the domain in non-empty) there is someone in relation with everyone. The derivation in natural deduction of $\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \to \exists y \forall x P(x,y)$ is the following (valid both in classical and intuitionistic logic):
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{[\forall x\forall y P(x,y)]^1}{\forall y P(x,y)}\small{\forall_{elim}}}{P(x,y)}\small{\forall_{elim}}}{\forall x P(x,y)}\small{\forall_{intro}}}{\exists y \forall x P(x,y)}\small{\exists_{intro}}}{\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \to \exists y \forall x P(x,y)}\small{\to_{intro}1}
$$

Comment: Never too late to upvote and accept an answer, thank you loads @Taroccoesbrocco

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what rules you have in your proof system.

Do you have any rule that can infer something from nothing, e.g. $\vdash p \lor \neg p$?

If not, try a proof by contradiction, i.e. Assume the negation, and now you have something to work with ... if you get to a contradiction, you can reject the assumption, and thus obtain the desired statement.

For the second problem, since you need to prove a conditional, do a conditional proof: assume the antecedent (the 'if' part), and try to derive the consequent (the 'then' part) from that. Presumably you have a rule that can point to that, and conclude the conditional as a whole.